# Выбор атрибутов в xsd схеме

Tags: xml, xsd

Необходимо у элемента сделать выбор:
Если есть атрибут1, то атрибут2 становится необязательным. Если есть атрибут2, то атрибут1 становится необязательным. В тоже время хотя бы один из атрибутов должен быть.

С Элементами xml такое проделывалось через элемент выбора. А как с атрибутами такое сделать?

Попытался сделать эти случаи разными элементами через выбор элемента, но проверка схемы говорит, что нельзя использовать выбор для элементов с одинаковым именем. Можно ли это как-то обойти?

Например:

- Правильное определение элемента:

  ```
  <element attr1="value" attr2="value"></element>
  <element attr1="value"></element>
  <element attr2="value"></element>
  ```
- Неправильное определение элемента:

  ```
  <element></element>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

На англоязычном StackOverflow [задавался похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386713/how-to-do-mutually-exclusive-attributes-in-xml-schema). Советуют использовать [RelaxNG](http://www.relaxng.org/).

В вашем случае код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
start = document
document = element document {elem+}
   elem = element elem {attr1 | attr2 | (attr1 & attr2)}
   attr1 = attribute attr1 {text}
   attr2 = attribute attr2 {text}
```